# How do I use Leaf.xnet Substring recursively

Tags: c#, substring, xnet

I am trying to retrieve password reset links with Leaf.xnet I have been using the Substring but it only loads the first substring when there a recursive amount of password reset emails, how would I be able to grab them all?

```
textbody.Substring("Reset", "You"));
```

Comment: What do you mean by recursive? Do you mean looping through all emails?

Comment: I mean by loading all of the substrings to a list not just one substring